# joined table results count mysql performance

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have `restaurants` table with structure, `id, name, table_count`, and `orders` table, with structure `restaruant_id, start_date, end_date, status`. I want to find those tables, that are available for some date range - as available - considered those , that either there are no orders , or number of confirmed reservations (status = 1) for the given date range is less than the number of table count for that restaurant. So, I use this query

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.table_count
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN orders o 
ON r.id = o.restaurant_id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL 
OR (r.table_count > (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM orders o2 
                WHERE o2.restaurant_id = r.id AND o2.status = 1 AND
                NOT(o.start_date >= '2013-09-10') AND NOT (o.end_date <= '2013-09-05')
            )
)
```

So, Can I make the same query in other way which will be faster. I am thinking in this, way, because during time it can be thousands or more rows in orders table, and because it should compare the dates columns to be between some date range, would it be faster result if I add a column `is_search`(with mysql index) with value 1 or 0, which can be updated by cron job, periodically checking and making reservations from the past as 0,  so during search only the orders of the present or of the future will be considered when comparing the date range(which I think much more expensive than compare tinyint column for 1 or 0). Or, adding that condition will add one more thing to check, and it will have the opposite effect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to index  on 0 and 1.In your case with thousonds of records the index  will have poor selecetivity and is posible to not be used at all.

You can speed up your query  if you build comoposite index on start_data and end_data. 
And rewrite query to using not "NOT" clause in dates columns. Because NOT is going to do the sort the tables instead of using the index.

You query

`...NOT(o.start_date >= '2013-09-10') AND NOT (o.end_date <= '2013-09-05')..`

could be defined

`...(o.start_date <'2013-09-10') AND  (o.end_date > '2013-09-05')...`